# Is any way to mock global variable in CppUTest?

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, cpputest

Is there any way to mock static global variable to use in test function? Or any workaround for that?

Below example of such situation:

```
static zsock_t *publish_logs =  NULL;

int btak_log_message_reactor(zloop_t *loop, zsock_t *reader, void *arg) {
    struct btak_log_message *message;
    size_t message_size;

    if(zsock_recv(reader, "b", &message, &message_size) == 0) {
        push_log_message(message);
        if(publish_logs)
            publish_log_message(message, publish_logs);
        free(message);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with CppUTest, but it's not possible to just create an accessor and return the mock variable when needed?

Comment: Yes, I've think about that. But in this way I produce not really usable code so I was wondering if there is possible to mock just the global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We often forget about the linker.  We can use a different object file to mock an interface.  This mock-obj would contain a different definition of your global.

But current unit test frameworks only work on code level...  So some build-fu will be needed to add mock objects to the test build.